# Next.js setting current active class with Link and router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I wanted to set an active class to the current page, but I'm missing something.

```
<Link href={`/projects/${project.id}`}>
  <a
    className={`${
      router.pathname === `/projects/${projects.id}`
        ? "active"
        : ""
    }`}
  >
    {project.title}
  </a>
</Link>
```

Not sure if this is the correct way, because when I console log `router.pathname`, I get `/projects/[id]`

Is this the correct way of doing this? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `router.asPath` in that sense.
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object
Just remember that it uses the literal path in the browser, with query strings and anchors.

Comment: Is there a better way in case if there are query strings and anchors on the pages?

Comment: There is some ways I can think of right of the top of my head.  
You could:
- manually strip asPath with `.split('#')` and `.split('?')`  
- pass the `activeId` from the serverSide all the way to your component  
- use `router.pathname` replacing `[id]` with `router.query.id`

Comment: What if there's like a url like `/projects/${projects.id}/something-else-beyond`, but its catching at least `/projects/${projects.id}/`?

Comment: If your link will stay active even though it is in a nested page then I recommend using the `activeId` prop idea or simply comparing the `router.query.id` property.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Active Classname

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

// we are providing here "href" as prop, children is <a/>
// activeLinkClass incase you want to provide different class in different pages. If you don't, default className "active"
export default function ActiveLink({ children, activeLinkClass, ...props }) {
  const { pathname } = useRouter();
  let className = children.props.className || "";
  // pathname=/marketplace
  if (pathname === props.href) {
    className = `${className} ${
      activeLinkClass ? activeLinkClass : "active"
    }`;
  }
  // we could write "children" but we would not be able to provide addional props
  //   this is wrapping <a>
  return <Link {...props}>{React.cloneElement(children, { className })}</Link>;
}
```

You can use this reusable component in any part of your project like this:

```
      <ActiveLink href={hrefOfPage}>
          <a>{project.title}</a>
        </ActiveLink>
```

as `href`, you get the current path of page, and it will be exact path. instead of `[id]` you will get the real Id, or if there is a query string you will also get the query string.