# How to get active link to work with dynamic sub paths in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using next/router to check for the current pathname and then conditionally rendering an active className.

Here is what I am doing:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter();

{
  navigation.map((item) => (
    <Link href={item.href}>
      <a
        key={item.name}
        className={classNames(
          router.pathname === item.href
            ? 'text-purple-700'
            : 'text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-white',
          'px-3 py-2 text-base font-medium',
        )}
        aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
      >
        {item.name}
      </a>
    </Link>
  ));
}
```

The issue is I'm also trying to display the active className for dynamic sub routes. For example /item.href/{id}, so it could be /blog/1.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js setting current active class with Link and router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095559/next-js-setting-current-active-class-with-link-and-router)? Use `router.asPath` instead of `router.pathname`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can get the id from router params with

```
const {id} = router.query
```

then your matching condition to check the route

```
router.pathname === item.href.replace('[id]', id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const router = useRouter();
const active = "text-purple-700";
const nonactive = "text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900 dark:hover:text-white";
{
  navigation.map((item) => (
    <Link href={item.href}>
      <a
        key={item.name}
        className={router.asPath == `${item.href}` ? `${active}` : `${normal}`}
        aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
      >
        {item.name}
      </a>
    </Link>
  ));
}
```